# php mcrypt not working after enabling it on docker container

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mcrypt

I am trying to install nginx+php-fpm with Laravel via docker, on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  I've been able to successfully get it up and running, however Laravel gives me an error: `Mcrypt PHP extension required.`

I've been able to install mcrypt via the command `docker-php-ext-install` within the container, but after installing it, and verifying that it's been installed and enabled (via `php-fpm -m |grep mcrypt`), I still get the `Mcrypt PHP extension required.` error.  Whenever I try to restart the php-fpm process or restart the container, elastic beanstalk spins up a brand new container and I have to re-install mcrypt all over again (basically wipes the slate clean).

I'm trying to make an automated script for all this, is there an easy way to do this?

This is my Dockerrun.aws.json file:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/src"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx-conf",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/nginx/conf.d"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "image": "php:5-fpm",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy",
      "image": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "php-app"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html"
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-nginx-proxy",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "nginx-conf",
          "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and my post-script that's run after the container is spun (placed in .ebextensions):

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_delayed_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      DOCKER_ID=`docker ps -q --filter "ancestor=php:5-fpm"`
      docker exec -i $DOCKER_ID bash -c "apt-get update"
      docker exec -i $DOCKER_ID bash -c "apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev"
      docker exec -i $DOCKER_ID bash -c "docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo pdo_mysql"
```

Comment: You didn't mention which version of Laravel you're trying to install. `mcrypt` PHP extension is considered abandonware and shouldn't be used, `openssl_` does its job much better. Your best solution would be to install newer version of Laravel which doesn't depend on `mcrypt` (I'm not exactly sure which version of Laravel depends of `mcrypt`, if any). If you don't need mcrypt, then your problem goes away and it seems you might solve it by using newer version of Laravel (5.3 for example), if that's a possibility for you.

Comment: i'm using Laravel 4.2

Comment: It is best not to use `mcrypt`, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. `mcrypt` has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create your own image and host it publicly on hub.docker.com. Docker containers exit when the main command stops so there is no way to reboot the php-fpm process after the container has started.

For instance:

```
FROM php:5-fpm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y php5-mcrypt
```

Then push this image to docker hub.

You could also set up an [automated build](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/), that way docker hub builds this image for you.

Then update your build definition image like this:

```
"name": "php-app",
"image": "jamesnine/php:5-fpm",
"essential": true,
```

Comment: that's what I thought.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note I just remembered that you have to put an `-y` flag at `apt-get install`, otherwise the build fails.

Comment: This might come across a bit pedantic, but for a somewhat beginners question it might be essential to get the terminology right: you would not host containers on hub.docker.com, but an *image*. you spin up a new container based on an image. Currently that container needs work (which isn't ideal), so this answer shows how to make a good image, that will result in a complete container. Quick type-up so it could very well be I mucked up some terminolgy as well, but the distinction image <> container is probably important here!